# Is a set of maps also a map?

Tags: functions, notation, set-theory

I am currently introducing some mathematical elements in my thesis and there is one object that is a set of multi-valued functions. I need to know whether a set of multi-valued functions is itself a single-valued function.

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be arbitrary sets. Further, let $M\equiv\{f,g\}$ be a set, where $f:A\rightrightarrows B$ and $g:A\rightrightarrows C$ are multi-valued functions. Last, let $\mathcal{M}$ be the set of all such sets $M$.

**Is it then possible to say that a set $M\equiv\{f,g\}$ is a single-valued function $M:A\to\mathcal{M}$?**

Thank you all for your help.

**Following hardmath’s answer, I have edited the original question.**

Comment: It is not uncommon to think of "tuples" as maps from an index set into a set whose contents are the desired kind of entries.   This is perhaps more familiar to you in the context of sequences, which are countably infinite tuples.

Comment: What is the meaning of $\alpha_i:\Lambda\rightrightarrows A_i$?

Comment: @Héctor I think you ought to explain (briefly) what you mean, because I think most people will not be able to guess.  Certainly I would never have guessed that notation meant a multivalued function. And frankly I don't understand why anyone would need game theory concepts to define one.

Comment: @Héctor I have only ever heard "map" and "correspondence" refer to single-valued functions. Actually some authors use "correspondence" for bijections.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have now clarified the notation I’m using a bit further.

Comment: I've deleted my post since it is obsolete.  Consider the case where $f=g$ for simplicity.  Why would you consider a set consisting of one multi-valued function to be a single-valued function?  Any possible motivation for considering an unordered pair (doubleton set) of multi-valued functions to be (instead) a single-valued function is less evident.  Typically when one thinks of a construct $X$ as if it were $Y$, one insists that the original construction $X$ could be recovered from $Y$.